# AlertDialog Default Button Divider Removal

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

The problem is that whenever a single item array is passed into the DialogFragment, there is an extra line (a divider perhaps) that is drawn above the cancel button.

[Single Item AlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzxpE.png)

When there are multiple items in the array, the dialog appears correctly.

[Multi-item AlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW0xH.png)

How can I get rid of the extra line in the single item alert dialog?

I'm using a DialogFragment to create an AlertDialog with an array resource

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int itemsId = 0;

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        itemsId = args.getInt(BUNDLE_ITEMS_ARRAY_ID_KEY, itemsId);
    }

    if (itemsId > 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setItems(itemsId, this).setCancelable(true)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
        return builder.create();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

I'm also customizing the alert dialog style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialog</item>
</style>
<style name="MyAlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It appears that the "divider" is just the bottom of the single list item. It is possible to change that, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to check for the single list item condition and then set the ListView divider's height to 0.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
if (getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(itemsId).length == 1)
    alertDialog.getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
return alertDialog;
```