# Divider between the options of alert dailog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using alert dialog to show actions as in whatsapp.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

And i am supplying the list of options using setItems() method

```
dialog.setItems(options.toArray(new String[options.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AddTaskActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

But problem is that it is also showing separator between different options like this, 
Screenshot:
[image]

Now the problem is that I want to hide the separators. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you mean you want to hide the lines ?

Comment: yes exactly this what i want

Comment: @Moudiz any suggestion ?

Comment: I though amy was helping you , do you still need any help ?

Comment: Thanks problem is resolved :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, according to this post [Alertdialog default button divider removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826016/alertdialog-default-button-divider-removal), the problem occurs, because your items are inflated in a ListView, with the layout simple_list_item - whose bottom is a divider. Solution was to set the divider height to 0:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```

Edit: tested on API 21 - no lines even without the addition.

Comment: I am not getting getListView() method as suggestion

Comment: In your code your `dialog` is a AlertDialog.Builder - not an AlertDialog as in my code. Please correct this :)

Comment: if I am doing like this.. AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); then dialog.setItems() is not working , please look at my code where it needs modifications

Comment: call setItems on your builder

Comment: Yes its working now :) I have done the same thanks :)